# Storing data in Redis not located locally

Tags: database, redis

I have an EC2 box which I SSH to often. I want to install a redis database in the box and query that frequently. Unfortunately, the code to store values in the database can not be run on the box since it gets 'killed'.

So I have been thinking of running the code on my personal laptop and storing the values to the Redis database on the box. So I need to query the database in the box again and again which is not on my laptop but that is on EC2.

Appreciate your help and time.

Thanks!!

Comment: What is the issue that you're trying to solve?

Comment: I am making a web service which needs access to the entries in database.